# degree of gauss map for genus $g$ torus in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, compact-manifolds

I read that the degree of the gauss map for a $M$ compact orientable $2-$manifold (connected to use the fact that those are only the $g-$torus) in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ should be $(1-g)$, which is $\frac{1}{2} \chi(\Sigma_g)$, where $\Sigma_g$ is the genus $g$ surface; which implies, among other things, the surjectivity of the gauss map when $g \ne 1$.

It should be a corollary of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59668/degree-of-gauss-map-equal-to-half-the-euler-characteristic-and-poincar%C3%A9-hopf).

Is there a proof of the fact which involves degree theory ? I found [this paper](https://cuhkmath.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/surjectivity-of-gauss-map-and-its-degree/) but it uses form-theory which I don't know yet.

**Edit :** I've been thinking about the problem since a while now and I realize that the easiest way to do it is actually produce a tangent outward to the boundary vector field with a proper number of isolated zeros,maybe $g-1$ saddle, which sums up to $\frac{1}{2}\chi(\Sigma_{g}) = 1-g$ and use the Hopf's Lemma in the following form :

> Hopf's Lemma : Let $M$ be a compact $n-$manifold in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
> with boundary, and let $X$ be a smooth vector field with isolated
> zeros that points outward to the boundary, i.e $\forall \hspace{0.1cm}
> > p \in \partial M, X(p) \in T_p M - C_p M$, then $\sum\limits_{X(p) =
> > 0} \text{ind}_X(p) = \text{deg}(\nu)$ where $\nu$ is a gaupp map for
> the boundary of $M$.

The definition of degree I'm using is : Let $M$ be compact $N$ connected with dim$M=$dim$N$, both without boundary, orientable and oriented. Take $f : M \longmapsto N$ of class $C^{\infty}$ then deg($f$) := $\sum\limits_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \text{sgn}df_x$ for $y \in \text{RegVal}(f)$.

The index of an isolated zero $p$ is defined as the pullback through a parametrization of the manifold of the index on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ so I'm going to give this definition : $\text{ind}_X(p) := \text{deg}(f_{r})$, where $f_r : \partial B(p,r) \longmapsto \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ with $f_r(q) := \frac{X(q)}{\lvert \lvert X(q) \rvert \rvert}$ for every $r \in (0,\epsilon)$ given $\epsilon$ the radius of the ball where there are no other zeros.

Any help on how to costruct the vector field would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @Elad "There is a proof of this fact, i.e. the degree of gauss map for manifolds as above which involves degree theory ?"

Comment: What is definition of degree are you using?

Comment: @Elad I've edited the question, including the two definition of degree and index I'm using, thanks.

Comment: You know about integration of differential forms?

Comment: @Elad Unfortunately not yet, those are the only definition I'm working with